# An item with the same key has already been added. After switching web hosts

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm transferring a .NET Framework 4.0 site from 1 web host to another.  The site on the existing hosting seems to be working as intended.  However, after transferring the site files and database to the new hosting and then fixing the web.config connection string to point to the new db, I'm getting errors when trying to access a page that pulls from the database.

I did not write the site, but it appears to be using a code-first setup.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
An item with the same key has already been added.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

Source Error:


Line 130:                if ((_Jobs == null))
Line 131:                {
Line 132:                    _Jobs = base.CreateObjectSet<Job>("Jobs");
Line 133:                }
Line 134:                return _Jobs;
```

I've tried rebuilding the edmx file from the new database server after transferring the files.  I know my connection string is working because I wrote a small test that connects to the database through the same connection string and it is able to retrieve data.

The only change I've made to the code base after copying it from it's working state is to the web.config's db connection string.

The only real notable difference from the old hosting versus the new hosting is that the old hosting was using SQLEXPRESS(unknown version), whereas the new hosting is using MSSQL 2008.

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +9378779
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.LoadRelationshipTypes() +650
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly() +17
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load() +25
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.Load() +4
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData) +160
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors) +166
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage) +316
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type type, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection) +84
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type type, Assembly callingAssembly) +151
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetTypeUsage(Type entityCLRType) +35
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetEntitySetForNameAndType(String entitySetName, Type entityCLRType, String exceptionParameterName) +33
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet(String entitySetName) +66
   PR.PRModel.PREntities.get_Jobs() in \\n5200-2\iis7_www\p\e\personallyrecommended.com.au\www\App_Code\PRModel.Designer.cs:132
   Careers.LoadJob() in \\n5200-2\iis7_www\p\e\personallyrecommended.com.au\www\Careers.aspx.cs:24
   Careers.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \\n5200-2\iis7_www\p\e\personallyrecommended.com.au\www\Careers.aspx.cs:16
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Connection String:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="PREntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.PRModel.csdl|res://*/App_Code.PRModel.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.PRModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=myserver.com;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="ConnectionStringDB" connectionString="Data Source=myserver.com;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: How did you transfer the database?

Comment: Could you show call stack? My bet that actual problem that you have two connection strings with the same name.

Comment: The web host sent me a database .bak file, i imported it to my local sqlexpress on my pc and then exported to the new webhost dbase.

Comment: that's likely and EF error - you're trying to `Add` an entity - which already exists - look up at that side what you might be doing wrong. Hard to help with that code.

Comment: right, i'm just curious why it was working on the old host but without any code changes it's broken on the new host.

Comment: How did you export that? The 'Export data' function in SQL Management Studio doesn't recreate the identity specification that increments the primary key. The code is probably trying to insert a row with an Id of 0.

Comment: millions of reasons :) that often happens when you throw in something new, it might expose some bugs you didn't think you have (check how you deal w/ entities, do you attach or reuse/check etc.) - or you might be having two active connections/db-s for some reason - just throwing here. Or what @ZippyV just said is also common - wrong initialization of things.

Comment: ZippyV, I thought of that as a possibility.  I did use the Export Data in SQLMS.  Do you have any recommendations on how to more properly transfer the data to the new server?

Comment: I don't know if my solution is the right one but I always use the 'Generate Scripts' wizard. In the list of options you need to make sure you enable 'Script data'. When you have the generated SQL script, right click that document and click 'Change connection' to connect to the new database server (make sure to select your db and not the Master db).

Comment: Looks like the assembly contains two `Job` types in different namespaces. Not sure why you'd only notice that after transferring binaries. I assume .Net versions are the same as well?

Comment: Yeah, both servers are .NET Framework 4.0.  Going the generate scripts route didn't seem to work.  Think it'd be better to start with no data and write an importer for the data using entity?

Comment: The data is not the problem. It's the design of your tables and the Primary Keys that are missing the Identity settings.